# Need assistance creating "Save As" method for SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a database and I have easily implemented both Save & Load methods however I am running into some trouble when trying to create a Save As method with C#. When I attempt to save out the changes this way it won't create a new file, it just doesn't do anything or it overwrites my original file even though I have given it it a new name.

To sum it up I want to open an .sdf file, make some changes to it and then save it with a new name. How do I do that?

I am guessing I am trying to make it easier than it is -- I am fairly new to programming databases so any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Here my Save As method:

```
public static bool SaveDataAs(string fileName)
{
   thisdb.dbFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
   thisdb.dbFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

   thisdb.connect();
   thisdb.SaveChanges();

   return true;
}
```

Here is my connect method:

```
public void connect()
{
   string dbConnection = "Data Source=" + dbFilePath + "\\" + dbFileName;

   if (!Directory.Exists(dbFilePath)) { 
      Directory.CreateDirectory(dbFilePath); 
   }

   string dbProvider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";

   Database.DefaultConnectionFactory =
            new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory(
                                     dbProvider, dbFilePath, dbConnection);
}
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you're up to here, but apart from that, what's the question?

Comment: Edited post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two very different responsibilities: saving data and file management. I would start separating the two.

Let there be a component that manages database files and knows about their locations. Let another component, your data access layer (DAL), save data to a database file that it receives from the file manager. The code may look like:

```
public Repository GetRepository(string fileName)
{
   var man = new DbFileManager();
   string dbFilePath = man.GetFile(fileName);

   return new Repository(dbFilePath); // TODO: Check dbFilePath
}
```

The DbFileManager knows the original database file and takes care of making a copy into the required location. It returns a Repository that communicates with the new file.

The Repository receives the name of the new location, builds the connection string and initializes a context with it. Then you can call any number of read and save actions on the repository.

I'm not sure whether this covers your requirements. If you want to modify your original file as well you could let the file manager overwrite it with the copy after your done updating. This way, there will always be an original file to return to in case of errors.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Just what I needed to get me moving in the right direction!